# Setting Canonical links in hyde templates

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, canonical-link, hyde

I'm a bit confused as to how to set a canonical link inside hyde's base template.  The jinja2 and hyde documentation isn't so clear as how to set the canonical from the base template (I'm not totally sure what the url parameter means in either)

What is the best way of going about this?